# Mathdesign-package (mdsffont.def) throws errors after MikTex 7300 update

Tags: mathdesign, miktex-update

When compiling

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[adobe-utopia]{mathdesign}

\begin{document}
Hello.
\end{document}
```

using MikTeX 7300 I get the following warning 16 times

> ```
> LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
>                It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
>                Found on input line 53.
> ```

where the input line number messages run over 53, 56, 59, 79, …

None of these warnings pop up when using MikTeX 7250 on a different machine.

I get that entries in the identified lines in the file `mdsffont.def` cause distress.

What can be done about this?

I did refresh font map files using the MikTeX console (administrator + user) without result.

Comment: These are warnings, not errors. They indicate that the mathdesign package should be corrected (he has been already notified) but they shouldn't harm.

Comment: @moewe yes sorry I should have spotted that, deleted my initial comment  (which wasn't exactly wrong but probably misleading...)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Where can I find an explanation of the changes? The new documentation for `psnfss` still lists `mc` as a series declaration. `changes.txt` refers me to `https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/299`for an explanation, but I don't know how to track down the relevant changes for `LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5`. I mean, I can `sed` all the `mc`s to `c`s but I have no idea why I'm doing that or what else is wrong.

Comment: @cfr possibly best place to start is the Feb issue of ltnews (`texdoc ltnews` issue 31, pdf pages 50-52) which describes the main changes.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. That's helpful, but is there anything in between `ltnews` and the source code? I'm pretty sure my font packages are going to break things, but I don't really know where to start. They're based on the Font Installation Guide code (including `nfssext.sty`), but that's obviously not current. Rather surprisingly, `cfr-lm` still seems to work as long as you don't say `\upshape` (my current solution), but other packages don't at all.